# check if element is display: block, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a subscription form that drops down on top of the navigation when the user clicks a button (#sub-header). this button is below the navigation. my navigation is fixed, so this button has a top of 60px, to keep it below the nav. however when the button is clicked and the subscription form drops down, then there is a space of 60px between the button and the navigation. i need to change the top of the button from 60px to 0px only when the subscription form is open. This is my code:

```
 if ($('.subscription-signup').css('display') == 'none') {
     $('#sub-header').css("top", "60px");
 } else if ($('.subscription-signup').css('display') == 'block') {
     $('#sub-header').css("top", "0px"); 
 };
```

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="subscription-signup">
    <div class="subscription-close" id="subscription-close">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="email-signup">  
      <form></form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the code to open the form (which works):

```
var $subscribeContent = $('.subscription-signup');
var $subscribeClose = $('#subscription-close');

$subscribeContent.hide();

$subscribe.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $subscribeContent.slideToggle();
});

 $subscribeClose.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
$subscribeContent.slideToggle();
});
```

For some reason, when the subscription form is open and is set to display: block, the top does not change to 0px. Is there something wrong with my code? Can anyone figure out how to do this?

Comment: Will you post the html code you're using? Thanks

Comment: @JerdineSabio just updated it!

Comment: Your JS says subscription-signup but your html says email-signup. Is that your problem?

Comment: _“This is my code:”_ - and where/when are you calling it?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$('.subscription-signup').is(':hidden')
```

instead

Comment: and $('.subscription-signup').is(':visible') for display block

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work either, i had actually tried this previously.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a class to the element?

```js
$subscribe.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.subscription-signup').addClass('subOpen');
  $subscribeContent.slideToggle();
});

$subscribeClose.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.subscription-signup').removeClass('subOpen');
  $subscribeContent.slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.subscription-signup {
  top: 0px;
}

.subOpen {
  top: 60px;
}
```